# Ajax post submitting form multiple-times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using this code for data sent by Ajax. I am using summernote editor. My problem is when I submit by missing any field, my from shows 'required alert' and then when I fill all fields and press submit button then the form sends an Ajax request two times. Until it happens every time I miss required field.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function (e) {
        jQuery('#btnSubmit').click(function(){ //btnSubmit is submit button id

            jQuery("#my_form").submit(function(event){
                event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action
                var post_url = jQuery(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
                var request_method = jQuery(this).attr("method"); //get form GET/POST method
                var form_data = new FormData(this); //Creates new FormData object
                jQuery.ajax({
                     url: "/demo/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=theme_submit",  

                    type: request_method,
                    data : form_data,
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData:false,
                    success:function(data){  
                    alert ('Data Successfully Inserted');
                    //location.reload();
                    //top.location.href="admin.php?page=data_list";
                    },

                })

            });
        })
    }); 
    </script>
```

Comment: Try adding a `event.preventDefault()` for the button as well.

Comment: You don't need `jQuery('#btnSubmit').click(function(){` AND `jQuery("#my_form").submit(function(event){` If you have both, it will submit twice.

Comment: remove your sentence: `jQuery('#btnSubmit').click(function(){`. The submit you have in `#myform` does the click if your form button has `type='submit'`

Comment: If I fill all fields at first time, then its submit form one time. I am use this `jQuery('#btnSubmit').click(function(){` because I am using summernote editor.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the submit out of the click. Write a function that would submit the form, and call it when the `#btnSubmit` is clicked. Below is the code to help you:

```js
jQuery('#btnSubmit').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action
  submitForm();
})

function submitForm() {
  var post_url = jQuery("#my_form").attr("action"); //get form action url
  var request_method = jQuery("#my_form").attr("method"); //get form GET/POST method
  var form = $('form').get(0);
  var form_data = new FormData(form) //Creates new FormData object
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/demo/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=theme_submit",

    type: request_method,
    data: form_data,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
      alert('Data Successfully Inserted');
      //location.reload();
      //top.location.href="admin.php?page=data_list";
    },

  })

}
```

Comment: Error showing: `TypeError: Argument 1 of FormData.constructor is not an object.
 

var form_data = new FormData("#my_form"); //Creates new FormData object`

Comment: I believe, we need to change `new FormData("#my_form")` to `new FormData($("#my_form"))`

Comment: still showing `TypeError: Argument 1 of FormData.constructor does not implement interface HTMLFormElement.
 

var form_data = new FormData($("#my_form")); //Creates new FormData object`

Comment: Seems `FormData` is expecting HTML object. In that case, it should be `var form = $('form').get(0);` And `var form_data = new FormData(form)`

Comment: now submitted form but not showing any required alert

Comment: Well, your code in the question doesn't have any validation code. Its only submission.